# c# Intercept constructor parameters

Tags: c#, reflection

I am attempting to write a job queuing system using C#.

Suppose I have the following class which represents a job to perform at a later date:

```
  public class TestJob : QueuableJob
    {
        private readonly string _t;
        private readonly string _e;
        public TestJob(string t, string e)
        {
            _t = t;
            _e = e;

        }
        public Task PerformWork(ITestService testService)
        {
            testService.Message($"Hello: {_t} {_e}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

I would like to be able to call something like:

```
JobQueueService.EnqueueJob(new TestJob("value1", "value2"));
```

In order to queue a job, I need serialize the parameters passed to the constructor of `TestJob`, so I can store them in a persistence layer (eg a database) and later deserialize them. Then I can instantiate the class and execute `PerformWork`. I would like to handle this as seamless as possible in my library so the end-user writing their "Job" classes doesn't have to worry about adding specific things for serialization.

I cannot figure out a way to "intercept" the parameters passed to the `TestJob` class without either losing strict typing (eg I could use `params object[] parameters`), or forcing the end user to implement some other code to help with serialization.

Currently, the most elegant solution I can think of (for the end user), is something like this:

```
public class TestJob : QueuableJob
    {
        private readonly string _t;
        private readonly string _e;
        public TestJob(string t, string e) : base(t,e)
        {
            _t = t;
            _e = e;

        }
        public Task PerformWork(ITestService testService)
        {
            testService.Message($"Hello: {_t} {_e}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

However, that would require the developer to remember to pass all of their parameters to base() (like `base(t,e)` in the example above). The compiler will not complain if they forget to do this, so it could be source of tricky bugs.
I've also tried to get the information using `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` in the QueuableJob constructor, however it don't believe I can obtain the *values* of the parameters from the stack.

Is there any way I can use reflection to "intercept" what is being passed into the TestJob constructor?

Comment: Look into DI / IoC framework that supports AOP like AutoFac. Alternatively change your design to have a type(s) that capture the meta data necessary to carry out the job and then a type to actually do the job that receives the metadata.

Comment: @Igor I ended up designing a type IJobParameters as a wrapper, which seems to be working so far

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I think this is necessarily the best way to approach the problem, but since you know more about this problem than I do, here is a way to get the names of the constructor parameters for a type:

```
var constructors = typeof(TestJob).GetConstructors();
var constructor = constructors[0];
foreach (var param in constructor.GetParameters())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Argument: {param.Position} is called {param.Name} and is a {param.ParameterType}");
}
```

Likewise, you can use reflection to retrieve the values on runtime and use `Activator.CreateInstance` to instantiate the objects again.